# Using `click` in a shell script that has a Hy program in a here document

Tags: python-click, hy

How can I convert the following working example of using click with `shell + python repl` (I think) to `hy`?

```py
python3 - "$@" <<'EOF'
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
EOF
```

When I use the following `hy` example with `./test.sh --name shadowrylander --count 3`, I get:

```
Usage: hy [OPTIONS]
Try 'hy --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (-)
```

when I should be getting:

```sh
Hello shadowrylander!
Hello shadowrylander!
Hello shadowrylander!
```

```
hy - "$@" <<'EOF'
(import click)

#@(
    (.command click)
    (.option click "--count" :default 1 :help "Number of greetings")
    (.option click "--name" :prompt "Your name" :help "The person to greet.")
    (defn hello
    [count name]
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    (for [x (range count)]
        (.echo click "Hello %s" % name)))
)

(if (= __name__ "__main__") (hello))
EOF
```

Normally I can use `hy - "$@" <<'EOF' ... EOF` without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is that click is confused by how Hy affects sys.argv or by how Hy partly replaces the Python interpreter.

As per [Kodiologist's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70488149/10827766), the answer is therefore as follows:

```
(import [sys [argv]])
(del (cut argv 0 1))
```

This will come right before the `click` call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about `click` to debug this, but as a Hy developer, I can verify that the error message is produced by `click` and not by Hy's own command-line-argument processing in `hy.cmdline`. It would take some digging to figure out whether `click` or Hy needs to be changed to make this work. My guess is that `click` is confused by how Hy affects `sys.argv` or by how Hy partly replaces the Python interpreter.

Your Hy program isn't quite right because it tries to use `%` as infix. The `.echo` form needs to be `(.echo click (% "Hello %s" name))`. With this change, and the Hy code saved to `test.hy` and run with `hy test.hy --name shadowrylander --count 3` (instead of using a shell script as an intermediary), it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; the answer was almost obvious: since hy is a python module, `python3` prepends the `hy` binary path to `argv`; so while `python3` would present `click` with `['-', '--name', 'shadowrylander', '--count', '3']`, `hy` presents `['/home/shadowrylander/.local/bin/hy', '-', '--name', 'shadowrylander', '--count', '3']` instead. Thanks for all the help, again!